# Getting value from nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have the following code that deserializes a JSON file, and then I need to iterate through the dictionary to get the innermost values and assign to a c# object:

```
public class Location
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Street { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Zip { get; set; }
}

string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.json");
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

foreach (var outer in dict)
{
    foreach (var middle in (Dictionary<string, object>)outer.Value)
    {
        foreach (var inner in (ArrayList)middle.Value)
        {
            foreach (var loc in (Dictionary<string, object>)inner)
            {
                var location = new Location();
                location.Id = ??;
                location.Name = ??;
                location.Street = ??;//...etc
            }
         }
    }
}
```

When I debug and step through the code, the value of innermost loop shows:

```
loc {[ID, 601391]}  System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>
    Key "ID"    string
    Value"601391"   object {string}
```

How can I get the value of `ID` and assign it to `location.Id`?

Comment: Why are you deserializing into a dictionary instead of just deserializing straight to your object???

Comment: @mituw16 he may not be in control of the data source

Comment: @JamesRalston You don't have to be in control of the data source to build an object that matches the source and then deserialize to that

Comment: @mituw16 true, I guess I could make it more broad an assume there may be other reasons for this method. It does seem like an odd structure though

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Key` and `Value` of the KeyValuePairs contained in the inner dictionary:

```
// outer loop
// middle loop
var location = new Location();
foreach (var loc in (Dictionary<string, object>)inner) {
    if (loc.Key == "ID") {
        location.Id = loc.Value.ToString();
        continue;
    }
    // if (loc.Key == "Name") ...
}
```

Or use the indexer to access certain named values (might be faster than looping over all entries).

```
// outer loop
// middle loop
var innerDict = (Dictionary<string, object>)inner;
var location = new Location();
if (innerDict.ContainsKey("ID")) {
    location.Id = innerDict["ID"];
}
```

Comment: it would be tedious and a but not useful to have conditions on each property

Comment: You are right, I added another solution which accesses the needed keys directly.

Comment: still seems it would need a check for each property

Answer (score -1):

You just need to cast the value and use reflection to make the code a bit more readable like this

```
var props = typeof(Location).GetProperties();

string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file.json");
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

foreach (var outer in dict)
{
    foreach (var middle in (Dictionary<string, object>)outer.Value)
    {
        foreach (var inner in (ArrayList)middle.Value)
        {
            foreach (var loc in (Dictionary<string, object>)inner)
            {
                var location = new Location();
                var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == loc.Key.ToUpper());

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(location, loc.Value);
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```